# Create website with a page to show online users including username and picture

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, social-networking

I am in the stages of the class diagram, I was creating the class diagram for a website I am planning to create. It was going fine until I reached the stage of wanting to have a web page that displayed the online users e.g. showing their username and profile picture of all online users. I am not sure on how I would do this, the image is of what I have so far. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Here is my current class diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyBgI.jpg

Comment: Well you have to do everything from scratch and you have nothing ... What do you consider as ONLINE users? real time or you update for example one field of the database each 5 min for ex. ?

Comment: I was hoping to have online users as users that are logged in and have not timed out, at the moment I am more focused on the database side but I was trying to establish the tables I would need in order to show the profile picture and username of the users currently signed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also set up a column for user's status (logged in, logged out) and make it toggle between 0 (logged out) and 1 (logged in). You could update this information every 5 seconds (in the background of course) using an AJAX call. Something like this:

```
//JAVASCRIPT
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.post('Path To PHP File', {x : Pass Variables, y: If You Want}, function(res)
                //Do something with the result (res)
            );
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>

//PHP FILE
<?php
//If you passed any variables to the script:
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];

//Connect to your database
$dbConn = "I hope you're using PDO for this.";

//Create your query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status=1";
$res = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();

//Return/echo results
foreach($res as $x) {
    echo "<div id='useTheIdToStyleTheResults'>".$x['name']."</div>";
}
?>
```

res is whatever your php script returns. You can simply run an SQL query on your database in that script to get all users who are logged in and use a foreach() loop to return each item as an html div element. Style those elements to your liking and there you go. If you have questions, just ask!

*EDIT:*
After reading a little more of your question, SQL JOIN and UNION are a couple of concepts you might want to look into.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

*EDIT #2:*

```
//Define Variables
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'userName';
$password = 'passWord';
$dbname = 'database in use';

//Create Connection
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected to database";  //Uncomment statement to the left to check for connection
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage();
    mysql_close($con);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: I used this structure to create a custom search box in a web based POS system I just finished a few weeks ago. It works great.

Comment: This makes sense, I was not planning on using PDO, is this a must? thanks

Comment: $con would be the variable you use here: $con->prepare($sql);

Comment: It's a much more secure way for your program to talk to a database. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

I would update a timestamp in the user's row every time they load a page and on the load of the online users I would check for timestamps that are fairly recent.

Pseudocode:
    SELECT username,avatar FROM users WHERE last_active >= time()-900;

Comment: Ok, in this case what is blocking you to display the online users?

Comment: I think because of my current class diagram, I will not be able to do this. For example I have "userstatus" that will have the values offline or online but for the online users page I will need to show their username and profile pictures as well which are not included in the table containing "userstatus"